# Mjml mail template not rendering UTF-8 on Yahoo Mail

Tags: yahoo-mail, mjml

I'm sending a mail template and it's not rendering UTF-8 characters correctly only on Yahoo Mail, which is quite weird.

MJML is adding by default utf-8 charset tag, I have not changed this default, and it's correctly appearing in the source code of the mail.

Do you have an idea of what could be wrong?

[image: yahoo mail]

[image: GMail]

[image: utftag]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by my client client which was not correctly sending the HTML header.

I managed to send `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` and it's now working fine in Yahoo Mail